# "ScrollView" doesn't work in "AlertDialog"?

Tags: java, android, xml

ScrollView has the following structure:

```
    
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>   
        <ScrollView>     
            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Does AlertDialog have restrictions on the use of ScrollView?

I tried writing parameters for ConstraintLayout in a nested ScrollView:

```
    
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustPan|adjustResize"
    android:fillViewport="true"
```

It didn't work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AlertDialog doesn't directly support scrollView, so you will need a CustomDialog for it.

```
public class CustomDialog extends Dialog {

    public CustomDialog(@NonNull Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context);
    }

    private void init(Context context) {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog_layout);
 
        ScrollView scrollView = findViewById(R.id.scrollView);
        // Add your views or set up the ScrollView as needed
 
        getWindow().setLayout(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
        );

        // Set any other properties or listeners as needed
    }
}
```

Instantiate it like below

```
CustomDialog customDialog = new CustomDialog(context);
customDialog.show();
```

Your scrolview

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <!-- Your content inside the ScrollView goes here -->

    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```